# Plugin Framework in Office for Outlook on Mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, ms-office, outlook-addin, office-addins

In windows, ms-office has the functionality of Installed Addins, wherein people can extend functionality of office. is there any such framwork for addins in **Mac**?

I have searched at many places, and ans i have found is no. the only way is by injection and swizzling. but I want some stable way to do it. I want to use office API's.

Answer (score 2):

You can use office addins
https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins

This will work on Mac also

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct, but it doesn't give complete access to all different sets of API's the way its provided in COM and VSTO add-ins.

Comment: @SahilDoshi: Using the Office addins mentioned in this answer is the way to go. Check out the latest version of the APIs, they are already quite powerful.

Comment: @DirkVollmar: my use case is to access attachments and might need to modify attachments in outlook based on users choice. I have searched through API's. But couldn't found way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this to use Office Web-Addins for development. This works for all the scenarios: Office Web, iOS, Android, Windows and Mac as you can install it from the Microsoft Store.